# how to load another xib file from another xib file on pressing button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

I am using two `xib` files of `UIView`. I want to show `Custominfoview` on pressing button from first `xib` view which is `FirstView`. I am little confused here how to do that. My codes is below please tell me how to do that. I have searched a lot but nothing found. I have attached a picture in link which is I exactly want.

[image]

```
class CustominfoView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var mainCustomView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infotextLbl: UILabel!

    // MARK:-
    // MARK:- Methods

    // MARK: UIView Methods

    required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder :aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let view = loadViewFromXib()
        view.frame = bounds
        // view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
        addSubview(view)

    }

    func loadViewFromXib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustominfoView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}


class FirstView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var mainCustomView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infotextLbl: UILabel!

    // MARK:-
    // MARK:- Methods

    // MARK: UIView Methods

    required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder :aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let view = loadViewFromXib()
        view.frame = bounds
        // view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
        addSubview(view)

    }

    func loadViewFromXib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustominfoView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

@IBAction func infoBtnpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print("Pressed")
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add customInfoView as a subview on top of the first view using addSubview.

(button pressed)

let customInfoView = CustomInfoView()

self.addSubview(customInfoView)

And then when you need to dismiss it simply remove it from the parent.

Comment: bro it is show view over the first view mean it is covering the whole first view ... i want to show like as my above picture when press the button it should show above the button.As you know button is already in another custom xib file

Comment: Then I'd suggest setting the variables frame for size/position before adding it as a subview.

Comment: after suggesting frame position..
it goes under the above two cells in the picture

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
@IBAction func infoBtnpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Pressed")
    let customInfoView = CustomInfoView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200) )
    self.addSubView(customInfoView)
}
```

In `CGRect` pass the frame value as desired. Also you should declare the `customInfoView` as `global` so that you can remove it easily.

Comment: i have added this statement..
CustomInfoView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: -160, width: 200, height: 200) )
sometimes it show above the view or some times it shows below the first view

Comment: it goes under the above two cells in the picture

Comment: @UmairShams Frame you have to handle according to your view.

Comment: Value of x,y,width and height should be respect to another view.